# Cannot login to jabber on iMessage from Xcode Server

Tags: xcode, xmpp, xcode-server

I configured my Xcode Server:

[image]

I added user account for `Users`:

[image]

Login into **Jabber** account in iMessage App.

[image]

but I can't login because of permanent alert:

[image]

What is the reason of this and how can I workaround this?

I followed [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33424901/2725435) from another question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found solution for your problem.

Check jabber settings in server terminal: `sudo serveradmin settings jabber`.

If property `jabber:hostsCommaDelimitedString` is different than your declared in Xcode Server host name change it. You can change like that:

`sudo serveradmin settings jabber:hostsCommaDelimitedString = "Cleverland.local"`

Next, you have to add your account in System Preferences -> Internet Accounts -> Add Other Account -> OS X Server Account. On the list you should found your local server, choose it.

[image]

In the Xcode Server go to **Messages** and choose preferred user.

[image]